# Working Around Performance & Memory Issues with spark-sql GROUP BY

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following example of running a `GROUP BY` with a relatively large number of aggregations and a relatively large number of groups:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
val h = new HiveContext(sc)
import h.implicits._

val num_columns = 3e3.toInt
val num_rows = 1e6.toInt
val num_groups = 1e5.toInt

case class Data(A: Long = (math.random*num_groups).toLong)

val table = (1 to num_rows).map(i => Data()).toDF

val aggregations = (1 to num_columns).map(i => s"count(1) as agg_$i")
table.registerTempTable("table")
val result = h.sql(s"select a, ${aggregations.mkString(",")} from table group by a")

// Write the result to make sure everyting is executed
result.save(s"result_${num_columns}_${num_rows}_${num_groups}.parquet", "parquet")
```

The input of this job is just 8MB, the output around 2.4GB and I am running this on a cluster with three worker machines with 61GB memory each. The result: All workers crash with OutOfMemory exceptions.
Even with lower values for `num_columns` the job becomes unreasonably slow due to the GC overhead.

Things we tried include:

- reducing the partition size (reduces the memory footprint but increases the bookkeeping overhead)
- pre-partitioning the data with a HashPartitioner before doing the aggregation (reduces the memory consumption but requires a full reshuffle before any real work happens)

Are there better ways to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Not an answer, but 61GB heaps on each worker are very large and going to cause very long GC pauses. It would be better to either have more, smaller workers or split up each server to run multiple executors with less heap to reduce GC pausing impact.

Comment: By "reducing the partition size" are you referring to adjusting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`? If not you could try increasing that number, default is 200.

Comment: @Rich, indeed, that's the parameter I've used. It solves the memory problems but I often see myself forced to increase it to unreasonably high values which again affects the performance due to the bookkeeping overhead.

Comment: have you considered trying to use aggregateByKey function from the PairRDD API? https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: @DanielM version of Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking almost universal solution to the problems like this one is to keep partition size at the reasonable size. While "reasonable" is slightly subjective and can vary from case to case 100-200MB is looks like good place to start.

I can easily aggregate example data you've provided on a single worker keeping default `spark.executor.memory` (1GB) and limiting total available resources to 8 cores and 8GB RAM. All of that by using 50 partitions and keeping aggregation time around 3 seconds without any special tunning (this is more or less consistent between 1.5.2 to 2.0.0).

So to summarize: either increase `spark.default.parallelism` or explicitly set number of partitions when creating `DataFrame` if possible. Default `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` should be enough for a small dataset like this one.

Comment: thanks a lot , but how to check size of each partition? is there any way i can check it from spark-UI ?

Answer (score -1):

As I am not sure what kind of aggregation function you are using, it is hard to say what spark does in the background. In any case, to have more control for each aggregation function, I would run a reduceByKey transformation for each one on the base RDD itself. Then, you can simple join the results if necessary. this way you have more control and can see which one of the aggregations "cost" you the most, plus you can avoid the group by operation which, beside the shuffling, can cause memory issues as well (due to the movement of entire sets of data into a single partition). following is a short illustration, where aggrigationFunctions is a list of your aggregation functions with their ID and actual function (a list of tuples).

```
val aggrigationResults = aggrigationFunctions.map( 
   f => {
     val aggRes = baseRdd
                     .map(x => (x.[the field to group by], x.[the value to aggrigate]))
                     .reduceByKey(f.func)
     (f.id, aggRes)
   }
)
```

Comment: You're mixing good old `groupByKey` (the one from _Avoid ..._) with `Dataset` operations. These things are not the same. In other other words `Dataset.groupBy` != `RDD.groupBy`.